# Qual forma é mais correto de não deixar executar uma função

Tags: php, return

Bom, não consegui achar um título mais especifico para minha pergunta, a minha dúvida é simples. Não vou enfeitar muito. Vamos lá.

Qual dessas duas estão corretas:

Sem **`return false`**;

```
public static function select($query, $array)
{
    if (!is_array($array))
    {
        die('Database select: Parameter two is not an array');
    }
}
```

Com **`return false`**;

```
public static function select($query, $array)
{
    if (!is_array($array))
    {
        die('Database select: Parameter two is not an array');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Gostaria de explicações caso alguma for incorreta, no meu ponto de vista a segunda opção é desnecessária pois o `die` já faz a aplicação parar não é? ou com o `return false` fica mais seguro ela não continuar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois do die não faz diferença o que você irá escrever, simplesmente `die` "mata" a execução e nada mais será executado após isto (com exceção de funções em `register_shutdown_function`), ou seja o `return false` nem vai chegar a retornar e você não vai conseguir nem pegar a resposta de `::select`.

Sendo uma classe eu acho bem errado usar `die` em caso de argumento em formato invalido, neste caso especifico (estou falando deste tipo de caso e não para qualquer "coisinha") uma exception cairia bem, como por exemplo a exception nativa do PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php

Exemplo de uso:

```
public static function select($query, $array)
{
    if (!is_array($array))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('O segundo parametro aceita somente arrays');
    }
}
```

Note também que desde o **PHP 5.3** existe para array e classe um certo tipo de tipagem em parametros de funções, `array` neste caso ficaria assim:

```
public static function select($query, array $array)
{
}
```

Então nem precisaria da exception.

Note que para capturar expcetion terá que usar try/catch, mas ai depende, porque de qualquer forma se emitir um erro assim é porque já existe algo de errado no uso da classe e nem deve ir para o servidor de produção, em desenvolvimento já atende bem.

Comment: Opa gostei da resposta, não posso dar +1 por conta da minha rep mas obrigado man

Comment: @Banks imagina, o que importa é que consegui lhe ajudar :)

Answer (score 0):

Colocar o retorno depois de um [`die`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.die.php) ou [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exit.php) não faz diferença, já que ambos (die e exit) vão parar a execução do programa, ou seja, nem vai chegar a executar o `return false;`

Observações:

- Retornar `false` também não é certeza de nada, dependendo do contexto, falso é uma saída possível e pode indicar que o programa encerrou com sucesso, depende de como sua aplicação irá interpretar esse retorno
- Também é possível usar uma sintaxe mais curta: `is_array($array) or die("Database select: Parameter two is not an array")`

Comment: Opa obrigado man não posso dar mais 1 por conta da minha rep mas obrigado

Comment: @Banks tranquilo